# Shouldn't the new "Marshall" badge be spelt "Marshal" instead?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges, spelling

Just out of curiosity, was the badge spelt "Marshall" with a double 'l' for a special purpose?

"Marshall" with a double 'l' is the name of [four famous men](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/marshall), while "marshal" means:

> an administrative officer of a U.S. judicial district who performs duties similar to those of a sheriff.

which would be more in keeping with "Deputy". Perhaps it was spelt after the name of some famous men on purpose?

Answer (score 32):

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marshal) (American), Macmillan [British](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/marshal) and [American](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/marshal), [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/marshal) (American), the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/114360) (access necessary e.g. through a university network), [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/marshal_1) (British), and [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/marshal_4) (British), **marshal** seems to be the variant more commonly used for the official/military title (in both British and American usage), hence I say **the badge name should be changed**. As mentioned before, the double-L variant mostly occurs as a last name. Some dictionaries list it as that, others don't at all.

Wikipedia may or may not be trusted in this matter, while [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshal](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Marshal&oldid=444391841) claims

> Marshal (also spelled marshall, more commonly in British English than American English)

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Marshall&oldid=424489689) says

> Marshall may refer to:
>
> - "Marshall", an American spelling for the military rank of marshal

Answer (score 20):

It would seem more correct with the one "l", although passable either way. But sure, we can rename that (next deploy).

Oh, and for the record - re

> In short, /blame Marc Gravell

I deny all blame here!

Comment: Can't blame you.. your last name ends with `ll` as well :)

Comment: Marc Gravellllllllllllllllllllllllllllll

Comment: @JeffAtwood I’m now hypnotised.

Answer (score 4):

I have a old family deputy US Marshall badge and have found 1890s spelling with 2 L's i.e.

> red dog saloon Wyatt Earp gun

I think it was a variant from British colonial times:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I already wondered that and may [I quote from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshal):

> Marshal (also spelled marshall, more commonly in British English than American English), is a word used in several official titles of various branches of society.

Comment: In short, `/blame` [Marc Gravell](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)

Comment: Huh, I was just looking myself and [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/marshal) suggests "marshall" is an alternative *US* spelling - not British. And all my British English spell checkers on this machine here go with "marshal", and only accept Marshall when capitalised.

Comment: @DMA57361: Well, [we could ask on English](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Strait we could, but the point is "marshall" is valid somewhere, so does it really matter since it's pretty clear what is meant? Also, Thursagen - the asker - is a very high rep English user anyway, so is more than capable of handling that themselves if necessary (it's probably not the kind of question they want thou', I suspect).

Comment: ["Marshal"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=marshal&searchmode=none) is the original spelling apparently. It comes from Old French, circa 13c. "Marshall" is a variant spelling, that seems to have come from George C. Marshall, a U.S. Secretary of State 1947-49.

Comment: Maréchal, from mareschal, from marhskalk circa 800 AD. It originally designated troops charged with caring for horses, a lowly task, but nonetheless delegated to trusted men due to the high value of horses.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to just rename it to 'Serialize'.